# MongoDB Update and Insert in two different collection

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, mongodb-query

**What I have :** Two collections

- User (Collection that contains user related information along with points he has)
- UserPoints (Collection which keeps track of when the point was given to user and when the points used by user. In short, a audit collection. UserPoints contains userId)

**What I want :** I want to update user's points in 'User' collections based on some criteria. At the same time I want to insert a document in 'UserPoints' collection for each user with entry of newly updated points and log.

**What I Tried :** I have written one updateMany query which I tried on some users which is working fine. It is updating user's point in 'User' collection. But problem is, I want userId who is been update so that I can make a entry in 'UserPoints' collection.

Is there a way to do this in MongoDB? (I am using version 3.2)

I was thinking of writing a simple C# program for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So is it you are trying to return a list/array of _id from the user.updateMany(), then use each one of the Users _ids to insert a new document into the UserPoints collection? And are you using .NET to do this?

Comment: I am a .net guy but I wanted this operation to be done using mongodb query as it would be easier. Doing this through .net code require creating a bsondocument for collection. Anyways I found a simpler solution which I will post in few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I used below query

```
db.users.find({
 "createdDate" : {"$gte": new Date("2017-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
                  "$lte": new Date("2018-02-28T00:00:00.000Z")}
         }).forEach(function(doc){
             if (doc.points > 0){
                    db.userPoints.insertOne({
                        userId: doc._id,
                        userCode: doc.userCode,
                        points: NumberInt(doc.points),
                        type: NumberInt(doc.userType),
                    });

                    db.users.updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: {
                        points: 0,
                        updatedDate: new ISODate("2018-08-02T00:00:00.000Z")
                    }}, false);
             }
         });
```